# How to add a pre-made profile to gnome terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome, user-profiles, xml

So I just re-installed Ubuntu, but before I did, I grabbed my old gnome-terminal profile.

Now I want to put that profile wherever it is that gnome keeps the profiles, so I can select it through the GUI. However, I can't seem to find the place it reads from.

I thought it was `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profile`, so I replaced that folder with my old profile folder, but this did not work.

I have searched my file system and I can't find any other directory that matches. However, I also can't find any folders or files with the name "unnamed", which is the name of the default profile that I have now.

I think I am in the right place, but perhaps I need to edit one of the xml files in the sub-tree.

Can anyone help me out?

`tree ~/.gconf`

---

```
.gconf
├── apps
│   ├── %gconf.xml
│   ├── gnome-terminal
│   │   ├── %gconf.xml
│   │   └── profiles    // these are the profiles I want gnome to pull
│   │       ├── Default
│   │       │   └── %gconf.xml
│   │       ├── %gconf.xml
│   │       └── Profile0
│   │           └── %gconf.xml
│   └── nm-applet
│       └── %gconf.xml
└── desktop
    ├── %gconf.xml
    └── gnome
        ├── applications
        │   ├── browser
        │   │   └── %gconf.xml
        │   └── %gconf.xml
        ├── %gconf.xml
        └── url-handlers
            ├── about
            │   └── %gconf.xml
            ├── %gconf.xml
            ├── http
            │   └── %gconf.xml
            ├── https
            │   └── %gconf.xml
            └── unknown
                └── %gconf.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the profiles created in 14.04 are not usable in the default gnome-terminal of 15.04 and 15.10.

I just opened a `gconf.xml` in an editor and manually copied all palette colors to the gnome-terminal profile preference.

You can view the settings you entered with `dconf-editor` instead of `gconf-editor`, in `org->gnome->terminal->legacy->profiles`.

I wish there was an import tool for backward compatibility...